# Accessing value from one k8s heml template in another file (Service from CronJob)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to access value/configuration from one k8s helm template file in another?

For example I have a service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8000
      name: http-admin
      protocol: TCP
  internalTrafficPolicy: Local
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: service
```

I want to create CronJob, that would reference defined port of the Service - is it possible?

Comment: Consider using `port: 80` to select the default HTTP port.

Answer (score 0):

Question: **In what form is your CronJob going to consume Service's port?** If it is in the form of environment variable, then you can simply define a field in your `values.yaml` file and reference it in both Service and CronJob's templates.

Comment: I simply want to call REST API against that service. I tried using variable/field from `values.yaml` but helm was complaining when I tried to use it in port definition in Service file.

Comment: Can your share the tenates that were causing the trouble? Also, what was the exact error?